# How to install AWS CloudHSM on Ubuntu 18.04 TLS? (requires libjson-c2 but only libjson-c3 available)

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04, pkcs#11, hsm, libjson

I am trying to install Amazon AWS CloudHSM on AWS EC2 instances running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

The instructions from Amazon seem to require an older library `libjson-c2`, but only the newer library `libjson-c3` is available for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Amazon link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/install-and-configure-client-linux.html

I am wondering if anyone can suggest a workaround, since `apt install libjson-c2` doesn't seem to work:

```
# apt install libjson-c2
...
E: Package 'libjson-c2' has no installation candidate
```

Has anyone had any success using AWS CloudHSM with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today (2018-12-22), Amazon does not yet support `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` (confirmed by AWS Support).  `CloudHSM` is only supported for `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution that worked for me. First install `libjson-c2` and then install `cloudhsm-client`.

```
    > wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/j/json-c/libjson-c2_0.11-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb
    > sudo dpkg -i libjson-c2_0.11-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb
    > wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudhsmv2-software/CloudHsmClient/Xenial/cloudhsm-client_latest_amd64.deb
    > sudo dpkg -i cloudhsm-client_latest_amd64.deb
```